# Is there a way to select parent div without knowing its class name or ID ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I have a graph i have made in javascript library d3. The size of it depends on the size of the window like so :

```
var GUIWidth = window.innerWidth;
var GUIHeight = window.innerHeight;
```

This works fine but what if i want to put this graph onto another page but make it smaller ? I dont want to go into here and adjust it, I want to be able to get the size of the container its held in and use that width and height.

But, in my case i don't know the ID of the container (because another person is developing the UI).

How do I get the ID (and width and height preferably) of the parent div that my graph is held in.

Here is example code :

```
var svg = d3.select("#interface") //this is my graphs container
    .append("div")
    .attr("id", "svgContainer")
    .attr("width", GUIWidth)
    .attr("height", GUIHeight);
```

Here `interface` is my graphs container but i want to do something like this to get the width and height :

```
var GUIWidth = $(parentOf('#interface')).innerWidth();
var GUIHeight = $(parentOf('#interface')).innerHeight();
```

Is this possible ?

Also I'd like to stick to javascript/jquery to do this as I'm using the `GUIWidth` & `GUIHeight` variables elsewhere in my code to determine sizes of other divs :)

Thankyou

Comment: `$('#interface').parent();`

Comment: Have you tried jQuery's [parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) function: `$('#interface').parent()` ?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean "ancestor" instead of "parent"? Either way, go to http://api.jquery.com and type the word into the search box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried this?

```
var GUIWidth = $('#interface').parent().innerWidth();
var GUIHeight = $('#interface').parent().innerHeight();
```